# Strassen factorization for $n \geq 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity

There is the famous Strassen matrix multiplication method (see [here](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen-Algorithmus) for further information).

In essence it boils down to the fact, that we can multiply 2x2 matrices with each other and don't have to use 8 multiplications, but $7$ instead.

When we would work with $3\times3$ or $4\times4$ etc. matrices instead, is there a way that we have to use significantly fewer multiplications than $n^3$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm

Comment: See [Matrix multiplication exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication#Matrix_multiplication_exponent) in particular.